# Put two centered divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

How can I put two centered divs next to each other, with some padding in between? I've tried `display: inline` but that doesn't seem to work.

```css
.my-container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  width: 20%;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Centered text */

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <img src="https://demo.keypasco.com/res-1.2.2/img/User_ring.png" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="centered">text</div>
</div>
<div class="my-container">
  <img src="https://demo.keypasco.com/res-1.2.2/img/User_ring.png" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="centered">text 2</div>
</div>
```

(Note: I'm also looking for a way to make the blue text-elipse a circle, but that's a different question I suppose.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` in your `.my-container` to align them side by side...

Also you will need to wrap your `.my-container` divs into a wrapper div with `text-aign:center` to align the inner inline items to center

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.my-container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  width: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Centered text */

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="my-container">
    <img src="https://demo.keypasco.com/res-1.2.2/img/User_ring.png" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="centered">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="my-container">
    <img src="https://demo.keypasco.com/res-1.2.2/img/User_ring.png" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="centered">text 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `display: inline-block;` to `my-container` class.

```css
  .my-container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
    width: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  /* Centered text */

  .centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <img src="https://demo.keypasco.com/res-1.2.2/img/User_ring.png" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="centered">text</div>
</div>
<div class="my-container">
  <img src="https://demo.keypasco.com/res-1.2.2/img/User_ring.png" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="centered">text 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: But now the divs are not center-aligned.

Comment: @lolbas what `inner content` you are reffering to?

Comment: Mislooked at DOM, edited comment.